# Shnayim Ushloshim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred thirty-two?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

132 are the responsa in [שו״ת הרמ״א](http://hebrewbooks.org/19551).

Answer (score 1):

The Bar-Kochva Revolt took place from 132-135 C.E.

Comment: Yeah, but the numbers that you are using for those years are not of Jewish significance. ;->

Comment: you are 100% correct. However could not think of anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Rabbeinu Bechayei (to Gen. 29:15) says that Rachel was five years old when Yaakov met her at the well. According to this, then, she was born when her future father-in-law (Yitzchak) was 132 years old (since he was 123 when Yaakov left home, and Yaakov arrived in Charan after studying in Ever's yeshivah for fourteen years).